# textfile parser: calculate start position with scala

Tags: scala

I am beginner in scala and I trying to implement the following algorithm.
I have the following input :

```
11 DFI1-MONT_TT_13 9(18) 14 IntegerType
11 SERI1-SENS_13 X(01) 06 StringType
11 DDRI1-MONT_TT_14 9(18) 12 IntegerType
11 SQRI1-SENS_14 X(01) 14 StringType
11 XCRI1-MONT_TT_15 9(18) 10 IntegerType
11 QSRI1-SENS_15 X(01) 08 StringType
11 WQRI1-DEVISE X(03) 07 StringType
```

and I want to calculate the start position for each field so my output shall look like :

```
11 DFI1-MONT_TT_13 9(18)  0  14 IntegerType
11 SERI1-SENS_13 X(01) 14  06 StringType
11 DDRI1-MONT_TT_14 9(18) 20  12 IntegerType
11 SQRI1-SENS_14 X(01) 32  14 StringType
11 XCRI1-MONT_TT_15 9(18)  46 10 IntegerType
11 QSRI1-SENS_15 X(01) 56  08 StringType
11 WQRI1-DEVISE X(03) 64 07 StringType
```

The start position can be calculated as follows :

```
startposition_line_n= startposition_line_n-1 + length_line_n-1
```

We are assuming that the first line start position is equal to 0

I already know that I can use the `scanLeft` or the `foldLeft` but as I am begining I don't now how to do this recursively . I took a sample from the dataset in input, currently it includes much more lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tail-recursive method that takes a `List[String]` as input and produces a new, modified, `List[String]` as output.

```
def setPos(input :List[String]
          ,pos   :Int=0
          ,acc   :List[String]=List()
          ) :List[String] =
  if (input.isEmpty) acc.reverse
  else {
    val line = input.head.split("\\s+")
    setPos(input.tail
          ,pos + line(3).toInt
          ,line.patch(3, Seq(pos.toString), 0).mkString(" ") :: acc)
  }
```

This assumes that the 3rd space-delimited field is always the offset integer. It will throw an error if that's not the case.

Comment: my input is rather a list of string, do you know how to convert it to an itertaot[String] so I can use this algorithm easily , I am currently getting the following error : cala:117: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: Iterator[String]

Comment: @ben; Code adjusted. It pays to be specific when when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, drop comments if you need some clarifications.

```
val input = List(
    "10 DFI1-MONT_TT_13 9(18) 14 IntegerType",
    "10 SERI1-SENS_13 X(01) 06 StringType",
    "10 DDRI1-MONT_TT_14 9(18) 12 IntegerType",
    "10 SQRI1-SENS_14 X(01) 14 StringType",
    "10 XCRI1-MONT_TT_15 9(18) 10 IntegerType",
    "10 QSRI1-SENS_15 X(01) 08 StringType",
    "10 WQRI1-DEVISE X(03) 07 StringType")
)

input.foldLeft((0, List[String]())) {
    case ((sum, acc), line) => {
        val sp = line.split(" ")
        val si = 3
        (sum + sp(si).toInt, acc :+ ((sp.take(si) :+ sum) ++ sp.takeRight(sp.size - si)).mkString(" "))
    }
}._2
```